# Crystal reports 11: How to handle or trim special characters

Tags: crystal-reports

In my crystal report, I noticed one of the fields being pulled from a table has special characters.  More specifically carriage returns and tabs.  Is there a way to strip this out, so it doesn't show up blank in my reports?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, if you want to remove tabs, the Chr code for that is Chr(9).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do it:

```
stringvar output := {TABLE_NAME.FIELD_NAME};
output := Trim(output);  //get rid of leading & trailing spaces
output := Replace(output,Chr(13),'');  //get rid of line feed character
output := Replace(output,Chr(10),'');  //get rid of carriage return character

//add any other special characters you want to strip out.
```

If you have a lot of characters to strip out, you can use this slightly fancier approach.  Just add whatever characters you want to strip out to the in[]:

```
stringvar input := {DROPME.TEST_FIELD};
stringvar output := '';
numbervar i;

input := Trim(input);

for i := 1 to Length(input) Step 1 do
  if not(input[i] in [Chr(13),Chr(10)]) then
    output := output + input[i];

output
```

Comment: I used Chr(13) & Chr(10) together since I want to converted a Windows/DOS carriage return to a HTML <br>. The top formula worked for that purpose as well. :)