# Crystal Reports - varying field size

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Guys, i have a crystal report with a combination of database fields and static text. 
Is it possible to resize the field or reduce white space between these fields and the static text?

> For ex: John works for **"fieldA "**, his
>   title is **"fieldB "**.

In some cases, there is significant white space between the static text and the field, say when the fieldA value has only few letters.

TIA

Comment: Only if you concatentate the two values together & handle the whitespace appropriate (I'd use a Cyrstal Reports function...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the database field right inside the static text field. In that case, you can put the text in the static text field on either side of the database field and resizing is automatic.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you are treating these separately?

For situations like this, you would typically make a static text box on the report, and drop the calculated field or database field directly into the middle of the text.

Alternatively, you could create a calculated field and include a formula: `"John works for """  + {FieldA} + """, his title is """ + {fieldB} + """."` (syntax will depend on the language being used).

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the white-space, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398260/crystal-reports-11-how-to-handle-or-trim-special-characters/398335#398335) might help.